# MS SQL Managment Studio: Saving Select Query with a left join leaves me with a ton of null values

Tags: sql-server, left-join

My goal is to suppress DEC from JAN using a unique id and export the results into a txt file. The query runs fine except for the fact that it returns a ton of null values (41 fields worth). I'm assuming these are from the DEC table due to the left join. This is my first attempt at a suppression like this. I am sure I am missing a simple statement to cure my ills but I am at a loss for what it might be. Or is there a more efficient technique than left join?

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Jan]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DEC]
            ON [DEC].[ID] = [Jan].[ID]
WHERE   [DEC].[SSN] IS NULL
```

Comment: then you need to add some more filtering in regards to what values you do not want to return based on IS NOT NULL` this is a no brainer personally speaking here is a site you should keep at your disposal [SQL Basics](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question, but u/MrTinkz is being helpful, so thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `*`, it is fetching everything for you.

Change `SELECT *` to `SELECT JAN.columnName`, `DEC.columnName`, etc. If you declare what columns you want from both tables, it should give you the right results.

Comment: I want all columns from JAN and none from DEC. Is there a way to write this without doing all 41 columns of JAN individually?

Comment: select JAN.* perhaps?

Comment: SELECT Jan.*
FROM Jan
        LEFT JOIN Dec
            ON Dec.ID = Jan.ID
WHERE   Dec.SSN IS NULL